# Ember array option with ember power select

Tags: ember.js

My model has 2 attributes (`baseCurrency` and `otherCurrencies`) whose values are selected in a form by 2 *ember power selects* dropdown menu whose options depend on 2 computed properties (`baseCurrencyOptions` and `otherCurrencyOptions`)

**controller**

```
  ...
  otherCurrencyOptions: Ember.computed('model.baseCurrency', function() {
    console.log(`allCurrencies changed to: ${this.get('allCurrencies')}`);
    return Ember.A(this.get('allCurrencies')).removeObject(this.get('model.baseCurrency'));
  }),
  baseCurrencyOptions: Ember.computed('model.otherCurrencies', function() {
    console.log(`allCurrencies changed to: ${this.get('allCurrencies')}`);
    return Ember.A(this.get('allCurrencies')).removeObjects(this.get('model.otherCurrencies'));
  })
  ...
```

`allCurrencies` property contains a list of all currencies and it is not supposed to change over time.

**template**

```
{{#power-select searchEnabled=true options=baseCurrencyOptions selected=model.baseCurrency onchange=(action (mut model.baseCurrency) as |currency|}}
  {{currency}}
{{/power-select}}
{{#power-select-multiple searchEnabled=true options=otherCurrencyOptions selected=model.otherCurrencies onchange=(action (mut model.otherCurrencies)) as |currency|}}
  {{currency}}
{{/power-select-multiple}}
```

Problem is that every time I select a currency in one or the other of both dropdown menus `allCurrencies` property gets updated loosing in an irreversibile manner every selected currency. I expected `Ember.A()` to create a brand new object without modifying `allCurrencies!. Moreover I got the following warning:

*DEPRECATION: You modified concatenatedTriggerClasses twice in a single render. This was unreliable in Ember 1.x and will be removed in Ember 3.0 [deprecation id: ember-views.render-double-modify]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ember.A` will not create brand new `Array`it will just implements `Ember.Enumerables` and array interfaces([reference](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/#toc_arrays)).

Here is my suggested options,

1)To create brand new Array, you can use `toArray` method. so change this
`Ember.A(this.get('allCurrencies'))` to `this.get('allCurrencies').toArray()`

2)Another option is, iterate `allCurrencies` using `forEach` and inside callback use iterate baseCurrency to check for the condition and fill otherCurrency Array.

```
var baseCurreny = this.get('model.baseCurrency');
var otherCurrency = [];
this.get('allCurrencies').forEach(function(item, index, self) {
    /*I assume id as your unique property to identify object
    if (!baseCurrency.findBy('id', item.id)) {
        otherCurrency.pushObject(item);
    }*/
    //or if its plain string then
    baseCurrency.forEach(function(baseItem) {
        if (item !== baseItem) {
            otherCurrency.pushObject(item);
        }
    });
});
```

3. Define Array of Currency object like `[{id:1,name:'Dollar',type:'base'},{id:2,name:'Yen',type:'other'}]`
   so that you can use computed macros to get `baseCurrencies` and `otherCurrencies`

```
    baseCurrencies:Ember.computed.filterBy('allCurrencies','type','base')
    otherCurrencies:Ember.computed.filterBy('allCurrencies','type','other')
```

Comment: Thanks @kumkanillam. I adopted the `toArray()` option with success. But I am still perplexed because I think [this](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_A) is a little bit misleading...

Comment: Even though they mentioned `Does not modify the original object` but still initial sentence(`Creates an Ember.NativeArray from an Array like object.`) leads to confusion. Join [slack community](https://embercommunity.slack.com) and join channel #-team-learning  and discuss with them and submit PullRequest. this will help others too. Learning team will welcome your PR.